# Show this increasing function on $\Bbb R$ is discontinuous at every rational number.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, self-learning

Let $\{q_k\}_1^\infty$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\chi_{(q_k,\infty]}(x).$$ I want to show this function is discontinuous at all rational points. I've seen discussion about this on mathexchange but then I really didnt fully understand any of the arguments that were presented.

I tried the following, let $r$ be rational number then there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r=q_n$. To show that $f$ is not continuous at $r$, I want to argue the left and right limit is not the same.
First consider $\delta>0$ and $x-r<\delta$ then there exists $q_l\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r<q_l<x$. Then $f(x)-f(r)>f(x)-f(q_l)=\displaystyle \sum_{k:q_k<q_n}\frac{1}{2^k}-\sum_{k:q_k<q_l}\frac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k:q_n< q_k<q_l}\frac{1}{2^k}=t>0$ where $t<\infty$ since the sum has to be countable.

On the other hand if we let $x<r$ then every $(q_k,\infty]$ contains $x$ also contains $r$ hence their difference approaches $0$ as $x\to r$.

Does this make sense at all? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $f(x)$? There should be some dependence of the right-hand side on $x$?

Comment: @JohnB hi Sorry I made an edited I think RHS the characteristic function depends on $x$.

Comment: $t$ depends on $x$, so it doesn't prove what you want (such an argument would also "prove" $g(x)=x$ is discontinuous everywhere).  The whole point you need to use is $x> r=q_n$ implies $f(x)-f(r) \geq 2^{-n}$.  Using $q_l$ as you did makes this estimate impossible and using $\delta$ just confuses the issue (we need $x-r>0$, not $x-r<\delta$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the ideas, so for that approach then if I have $f(x)-f(r)=\displaystyle \sum_{k:q_k<q_n}\frac{1}{2^k}-\sum_{k:q_n\leq q_k<x}\frac{1}{2^k}$ But I have played around with this equation for a long time today and I couldnt convince myself $\displaystyle \sum_{k:q_k<q_n}\frac{1}{2^k}-\sum_{k:q_n\leq q_k<x}\frac{1}{2^k}=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}$.

Comment: I don't know why you've written that equation for $f(x)-f(r)$, but $x > r=q_n$ implies $$f(x)-f(r)=\sum_{k : q_k < x} \frac{1}{2^k} - \sum_{k: q_k<q_n}\frac{1}{2^k} = \sum_{k : q_n \leq q_k < x} \frac1{2^k}$$ and the last sum always includes $k=n$ because $q_n \leq q_n < x$

Comment: @BrianMoehring omg Im so stupid, thanks! it makes sense now, I wasted so much time on this.